# Building post request with Django Test Client post data

Tags: python, django

when posting a form using my browser the post request from the views side looks like this

**GOOD:**

```
POST <QueryDict: {u'form_data': [u'{"kkz":"ALF" ....]}>
```

When using test client like this

```
data = { 'form_data': {
                   "kkz": "ALF",
                     ..
               }
            }
....
c = Client()
response = c.post('/wizard/....',
                       data=json.dumps(data),
                       content_type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

I'm getting this
**BAD:**

```
POST <QueryDict: {u'{"form_data": {"kkz": "ALF" ...}>
```

Which the view can't handle.
Where am i wrong ?

**update:**
This is the javascript part

```
                $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '/wizard/....',
                data: {
                    form_data: JSON.stringify(form.get_data(), {})
                },
```

where form.het data returns an array of [key: value, key: value]

**Solution: Thank you all !**

```
        form_data = {
            "kkz": "ALF",
              ...
        }
    c = Client()
    response = c.post('/wizard/...',
                        {'form_data': json.dumps(form_data)}
                     )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have shown the way "your browser" is creating this post data.

Presumably, you are using some Javascript that looks something like this:

```
$.post(url, { form_data: JSON.stringify(data) }, ...)
```

You need to follow the same structure, using a dict containing a "form_data" key.

```
data = {
          "kkz": "ALF",
           ..
        }
....
response = c.post('/wizard/....',
                  data={'form_data': json.dumps(data)},
                  content_type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

Comment: POST <QueryDict: {u"[{'kkz': 'ALF'}]": [u'']}> Somehow it's using form_data as key and adding an empty value [u'']

Comment: You wouldn't get that from this code. Are you sure you passed the form_data key as I show?